# DD-WRT: How can I Guess via CLI shell the link quality of each wifi associated client?

Tags: wireless-networking, command-line, dd-wrt

When dealing with **OpenWRT**, I use this method to know the **link quality** of associated wireless clients (AP mode):

```
root@AP-0:~# iw dev wlan0 station dump
Station 4c:74:03:f2:15:27 (on wlan0)
        inactive time:  5050 ms
        rx bytes:       10053
        rx packets:     70
        tx bytes:       6004
        tx packets:     46
        tx retries:     20
        tx failed:      0
        signal:         -84 [-86, -91] dBm
        signal avg:     -83 [-85, -88] dBm
        tx bitrate:     21.7 MBit/s MCS 2 short GI
        rx bitrate:     6.0 MBit/s
        authorized:     yes
        authenticated:  yes
        preamble:       short
        WMM/WME:        no
        MFP:            no
        TDLS peer:      no
```

I use to look primarily at the two *bitrate* fields, since a bad wifi link uses to slow down speed.

But on **DD-WRT** for my **Buffalo WHR-HP-G54** I only have this command that yields no bitrate nor noise info for associated clients:

```
~ # /usr/sbin/wl assoclist
assoclist E4:9A:79:5E:F6:DD
assoclist 2C:F0:EE:7B:00:B4
assoclist 84:DB:AC:A6:B4:E6
assoclist B0:34:95:27:F4:B6
```

I know that via GUI I can get this info, but reaching it via command-line is more useful,  as long as I can script and parse the data.

Is there any way to **know the link quality** for **each** connected wifi client?

Further Data:

- I have asked this question at [DD-WRT forum](http://www.dd-wrt.com/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?p=1074583#1074583), with no luck.
- The `wl` embedded command seems not to give this info, or I have not been able to find it.

Answer (score 0):

Found the information you need here:

```
for INTERFACE in $(nvram get wl_ifnames)
do
  for CLIENT in $(wl -i $INTERFACE assoclist | sed 's/assoclist//')
  do
    echo $INTERFACE $CLIENT $(wl -i $INTERFACE rssi $CLIENT)
  done
done
```

- http://www.linksysinfo.org/index.php?threads/outrageously-high-quality-in-device-list-shibby.68649/
- https://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Wl_command

OK in the above code snip the nvram command gets the wireless interface names like so:

```
# echo $(nvram get wl_ifnames)
eth1 eth2
```

wl assoclist gives you the MAC addresses of every connected client:

```
# wl -i eth2 assoclist
assoclist 11:11:11:11:11:11
assoclist 22:22:22:22:22:22
```

use rssi to get the signal strength of each one:

```
# wl -i eth2 rssi 22:22:22:22:22:22
-64
```

use sta_info to get additional data

```
# wl -i eth2 sta_info 22:22:22:22:22:22
 STA 22:22:22:22:22:22:
         aid:1
         rateset [ 6 9 12 18 24 36 48 54 ]
         idle 2 seconds
         in network 1647 seconds
         state: AUTHENTICATED ASSOCIATED AUTHORIZED
         flags 0x11e13b: BRCM WME PS N_CAP VHT_CAP AMPDU AMSDU
         HT caps 0x6f: LDPC 40MHz SGI20 SGI40
         VHT caps 0x63: LDPC SGI80 SU-BFR SU-BFE
         tx data pkts: 959451
         tx data bytes: 199701001
         tx ucast pkts: 16565
         tx ucast bytes: 40283979
         tx mcast/bcast pkts: 942886
         tx mcast/bcast bytes: 159417022
         tx failures: 0
         rx data pkts: 9659
         rx data bytes: 1144526
         rx ucast pkts: 9650
         rx ucast bytes: 1143442
         rx mcast/bcast pkts: 9
         rx mcast/bcast bytes: 1084
         rate of last tx pkt: 866667 kbps
         rate of last rx pkt: 24000 kbps
         rx decrypt succeeds: 7880
         rx decrypt failures: 1
         tx data pkts retried: 15
         tx data pkts retry exhausted: 0
         per antenna rssi of last rx data frame: -68 -71 -66 0
         per antenna average rssi of rx data frames: -68 -71 -64 0
         per antenna noise floor: -98 -98 -98 0
```

Comment: Could you please expand with some example?